# /stylesheets/application.css routing error on heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

An application error constantly occurs:

```
2014-11-26T06:45:10.349830+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"):
```

In my application.html I have:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

In my production.rb, because heroku is not serving and the application should serve static assets I have:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

On the live site I have:

```
<link href="/assets/application-da7e0e08bb87fbae6f1225fa189fab8e.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The url

```
mysite/assets/application-da7e0e08bb87fbae6f1225fa189fab8e.css
```

returns a result.

The url

```
mysite/assets/application.css
```

also returns a result.

Everything is working fine, but there is this error message in the log and I can not understand why. Who requests /stylesheets/application.css and why and how to stop this error from occurring.

Rails is "3.2.16"

Answer (score 0):

There should be two problems:

1) add  %`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`>

2) It looks like you have added assets precompiled file in your git repo. Ideally, it shouldn't be there since heroku can this for you whenever you push it.

To fix this, you have to do this

1. git rm -r public/assets/
2. add public/assets/** in your .gitignore file
3. git add .
4. git commit -am "allow heroku auto assets precompilation"
   5.git push heroku master

Comment: I will try the 1)
I do not want to do 2) because in this way heroku precompiles on every commit and it takes something like 15-20 minutes. About 1% of my commits are connected with the assets and that`s way I am precompiling them locally